# Jquery, while, each: how to test if all :selected is not 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, while-loop, each

I have a form that has a few select dropdowns, and I want to make sure that at least one has the default of '0' changed to something else. However, I can't get my mind around how to do it. I've tried both .each() and a while statement, and neither behaves like I expect it to.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form>
        <label>Qty:</label>
        <select class="Qty">
            <option selected="selected">0</option>
            <option>1</option>

       </select>
       <br />
       <label>Qty:</label>
        <select class="Qty">
            <option selected="selected">0</option>
            <option>1</option>
       </select>
       <br />
       <br />
       <label>Qty:</label>
        <select class="Qty">
            <option selected="selected">0</option>
            <option>1</option>
       </select>
       <br />
       <a href="#">test</a>
</form>
```

and here is the while statement:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        while ($('select > option:selected').val()==0){
                alert('hello');

            } 
    });
```

Unless all the selects are set to something other than 0, it gets stuck in a loop where it keeps testing the selects (so the hello alert keeps coming up).

I tried each as well.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('select > option:selected').each(function (i) {
            if($(this).val()>0) {
                alert('okay to proceed');
            } else {
                alert('nothing found');
            }
        });
    });
```

This is a little better, but it keeps checking even after its found the true answer. So if I try to trigger an error message, it will say everything is okay but then trigger the error message still.
I also tried setting a variable for if its valid or not, but it keeps showing up as false:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var valid = false;
        $('select > option:selected').each(function (i) {
            if($(this).val()>0) {
                var valid= true;
                alert(valid);
            }
        });
        if(valid==true) {
            alert(valid);
            alert('it works');
        } else {
            alert(valid);
            alert('uh-oh');
        }
    });
```

I'm clearly missing something. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first try, the `while` statement, it will keep looping because:

`$('select > option:selected').val()` will always `==0` and it never leaves the loop.

For the `.each` you can break the loop when it is found by `return false` as mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

For the last, you declare `var` inside the `.each(function()` which means it is only defined within that function and as soon as it goes to the next `each` in the selection the `var` will be redefined -- once it has exited the `.each` it is no longer declared.

So working off your last example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFnBR/1/)

```
 $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     var found = false;
     $('select').each(function(){
         if($(this).val()!=0){
             found = true;
             return false;
         }
     });
     if(found)
     {
         alert('success');
     }
     else
     {
         alert('failed');
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @WSkid! So I was close, just not there yet. I appreciate you pointing out the return false; so I'm using that as well too. Is there a benefit to using `$(this).val()!=0` over `$(this).val()>0` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just working on getting the final iteration of your code fixed. The reason that valid is always showing up as false is because you define a new variable called valid which is local to the closure provided to the each method. This hides the outer variable which remains unchanged.

Update your code to

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = false;
    $('select > option:selected').each(function (i) {
        if($(this).val()>0) {
            valid= true;
            alert(valid);
        }
    });
    if(valid) {
        alert(valid);
        alert('it works');
    } else {
        alert(valid);
        alert('uh-oh');
    }
});
```

and everything should work (I've removed the var keyword from within the each closure). [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) some more documentation on scope within JS which might help.

Once you've found the first non-zero selected option you can stop the each loop from continuing by returning false, i.e

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = false;
    $('select > option:selected').each(function (i) {
        if($(this).val()>0) {
            valid= true;
            alert(valid);
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(valid) {
        alert(valid);
        alert('it works');
    } else {
        alert(valid);
        alert('uh-oh');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but to get a value of select use `$('select').val()` other than trying to get option's `val()`

and to set values to options you have to set `<option value="0">0</option>`

so

```
$('select').each(function(){
   if($(this).val()==0){
      dostuff
   }
})
```